# How to Configure JAXRS and Spring With Annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations, jetty

I am working on a little Spring web service project.  Here is an example route:

```
package com.example.api;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Provider
public class WebServiceRoutes {

    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    public String health() {
        return "Hello";
    }

}
```

Then in my Spring configuration class:

```
package com.example.api;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class SpringContextConfiguration {

    @Bean( destroyMethod = "shutdown" )
    public SpringBus cxf() {
        return new SpringBus();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebServiceRoutes webServiceRoutes() {
        return new WebServiceRoutes();
    }
}
```

And finally in my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0">
    <display-name>api</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.api.SpringContextConfiguration</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

However, when I deploy this as a war file in jetty, and attempt to request /api/hello I receive the message:  "No service was found." with status 404.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to request /hello instead of /api/hello? The CXFServlet is mapped to `/*` not `/api/*`.